# Applying function method(calling a function) for factorial

Tags: java, factorial

```
public static void main (String args [])  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    int factor=1;
    System.out.println("Enter a number to find the factorial of it: ");
    number= sc.nextInt();
    factor=factorial(number);
    if (number < 1 || number > 10)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid!! the number has to be between 1 and 10");
    }
    System.out.println("The factorial of  "+number+" is = " +factor);        
}

public static int factorial (int number) {
    int result = 1;
    if (number < 1 || number > 10)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid!! the number has to be between 1 and 10");
    }
    else {
        for(int x=1; x<=number; x++ ) {
            result= result*x;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

My code works fine but if I input 11, it says invalid message and it also calculates the factorial for 11 which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the code that checks the range of the user input so that it's *above* the call to the `factorial()` function:

```
public static void main (String args [])  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    int factor=1;
    System.out.println("Enter a number to find the factorial of it: ");
    number= sc.nextInt();
    if (number < 1 || number > 10) {
        System.out.println("Invalid!! the number has to be between 1 and 10");
    } else {
        factor=factorial(number);
        System.out.println("The factorial of  "+number+" is = " +factor);
    }
}
```

Note that the call to `factorial()` and the `println()` statement are both inside the new `else` block now. Thus, if the user enters an invalid number, the only response given by the program is the error message.

If you also want error checking in `factorial()`, the clearest way to do that would probably be to throw a [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) when an invalid input is given:

```
public static int factorial (int number) {
    int result = 1;
    if (number < 1 || number > 10)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid!! the number has to be between 1 and 10");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Factorial input has to be between 1 and 10");
    }

    // rest of your code....
}
```